# Cloudflare $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] is never sent

Tags: php, cloudflare

I am trying to output the visiting user's country code using Cloudflare Geolocation.
I already enabled it for my website and used `$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]` but the value is never sent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: CF only adds a header `CF-IPCountry`, but that does not necessarily mean that your PHP setup generates a `HTTP_…` entry in $_SERVER. Do a var_dump of $_SERVER to see if it maybe gets passed under a different key, and if not use `getallheaders` and fish it out of there yourself.

Comment: I checked it and Cloudflare never added any headers to the request.

Comment: can you send a screenshot of your cloudflare configuration. both ipcountry and dns, do not forget to hide ip adresses from screenshot

Answer (score 1):

On Cloudflare control panel: **Network** -> **IP Geolocation**
You must activate the option with the button on

Comment: In this case, you must ask Cloudflare, because for me it works very well.

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare as a proxy, not just DNS ?

Comment: just DNS not a proxy. Should I change it ?

Comment: Yes, because Cloudflare is mainly used for its acceleration as a proxy. And no geolocation if you do not use it as a proxy!

Answer (score 0):

If Cloudflare IP geolocation is on but still not working, then you need to add this code to your .htacess file.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:vary=%{HTTP:CF-IPCountry}]
```

Also with the recently updated note by Cloudflare you need to activate it from the Cloudflare account ->Your Site -> Rules -> Transform Rules -> Managed Transforms -> From here enable 'add visitor location headers'

More details here:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/managed-transforms/configure/

Comment: I just enabled these and still no change
also added to htaccess